# Update query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

Ok...I'm using a mySQL DB and this code snippet is part of a login process that is called from a flex coded swf

The code essentially does two things:

1) Checks for existance of a record and then checks period difference if that record exists

If the record exists and is older than six months it will do an update query

2) If no record exists it will use an insert

WHAT"S HAPPENNING...the insert works great...and the update query works except the values for Company and LastName are removed and no value is stored in the database

Why? That is the ten million dollar question...why is the update portion of this code not updating the Company and LastName fields?

**Code Below**

//This function handles the request from the Update Contact Information popup window in flex to update the records in the database

```
function updateContactInformation() {

    //Initialize variable for result
    $Result = false;

    //ESTABLISH A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
    global $Return;
    global $mysql;  
    global $username;


    //ACQUIRE VALUES FROM THE HTTPS REQUEST(FLEX)
    //mysql_real_escape_string is used to ensure no code is injected into the input fields 
    $uUCI_MSUN = mysql_real_escape_string($username); //value used in DB to associate login username with the users formal name

    $uUCI_firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);//first name of user
    $uUCI_lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ["lastname"]);//last name of user
    $uUCI_company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ["company"]);//Name of users company
    $uUCI_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]); //email of the user
    $uUCI_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]); //phone # of the user
    //** Note: we do not collect time as the database will automatically update the Last_Updated_Date field with a new timestamp when the record is added or modified

    //CHECK TO SEE IF A RECORD EXISTS FOR THE USER ***by checking number of rows returned in a query for login username
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT MS_UserName FROM usercontactinformation WHERE MS_UserName = '" . $uUCI_MSUN . "'"))){
        // UPDATE RECORD IN DATABASE 
            $query2 = "UPDATE usercontactinformation SET FirstName = '" . $uUCI_firstname . "', LastName = '" . $uUCI_lastname . "', Company = '" . $uUCI_company . "', Email = '" . $uUCI_email . "', Phone = '" . $uUCI_phone ."' WHERE idUserContactInformation = " . getUID($username) . " ;";
            //send Request to mySQL
            $Result = mysql_query($query2, $mysql);


    } else {
        //INSERT NEW RECORD INTO DATABASE
            $query ="INSERT INTO usercontactinformation (MS_UserName,FirstName,LastName,Company,Email,Phone) VALUES('" . $uUCI_MSUN . "','" . $uUCI_firstname . "','" . $uUCI_lastname . "','" . $uUCI_company . "','" . $uUCI_email . "','" . $uUCI_phone . "');";
            //send Request to mySQL
            $Result = mysql_query($query, $mysql);


    }


    //RETURN A RESULT TO FLEX

    if ($Result) {
        $Return .= "<SuccessCode>1</SuccessCode>";
    } else {
        $Return .= "<SuccessCode>0</SuccessCode>";
    }

}

function getUID($username) {
    global $mysql;      //access Global mysql connection

    //Create Query to verify user exists and check difference between current date and Date Last Modified for the Users Contact Information
    $query = "Select idUserContactInformation from mydatabasename.UserContactInformation where MS_username = '" . $username . "'";
    //Send The Query To the SQL server
    $result = mysql_query($query, $mysql); 
    //parse results and return access level to calling function

    while ( $User = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) { 
        return $User->idUserContactInformation;

    }

}
$Return .= "</Result>";
print ($Return)
```

Somone asked for the form values...the below code is a snippet from flex that passes the form value to the PHP file

public function useHttpService():void {
               //Alert.show("Use HTTPS");

```
            service = new HTTPService();
            service.method = "POST";
            service.useProxy  = false;
            service.url = parentApplication.relativeDir + "/somepath/phpfileprocessinginformation.php";
            service.request.req = "updateContactInformation";
            service.request.username = parentApplication.User.username;
            service.request.password = parentApplication.User.password;

            //pass user supplied new information to query
            service.request.firstname = firstname.text;
            service.request.lastname = lastname.text;
            service.request.company = company.text;
            service.request.email = email.text;
            service.request.phone = phone.text;


            service.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, httpResult);
            service.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, httpFault);

            service.send();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra spaces in the two lines of code where you should be getting those values:

```
... $_POST ["lastname"]);//last name of user
... $_POST ["company"]);//Name of users company
```

That is not the same as:

```
... $_POST["lastname"]);//last name of user
... $_POST["company"]);//Name of users company
```

HTH.

Comment: I removed the spaces..still doesn't work as it should...same problem persists

Comment: Can you post the markup for the form itself? The only other problem I could see would be that you are trying to access keys that don't exist in the $_POST array. If you're able to safely do so, it also helps to print the query string to the browser so that you can see what you're sending to MySQL.

Comment: The same post variables are used in the insert query and they work...as far as the form..it's just a simple HTTPS Request built in flex that passes the variable to the PHP script

Comment: I added it to the original post...at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Not a big PHP guy -- found this question when looking through the MySQL stuff -- so I'm not sure this is valid at all, but where you're setting the lastname and company variables you have a space between $_POST and the bracket ([), could that be the problem? (The other ones don't have the space.)

Comment: I fixed the space, doesn't seem to change the outcome...and yeah..I made sure to save the PHP file...ha ha...done that before

Comment: 3 minutes before yours was given the exact same answer, this doesn't really add much...

Comment: @DamienPirsy - It showed up ahead of mine after I hit submit, sorry.